# What vessel did I photograph? How would I tell?

Tags: ships

On the 3rd of April at the Isle of Man, I photographed a large passenger ship (cruise ship, cruise ferry, or RO/RO ferry), maybe 10–20 km off the west coast:

[image: Photo at 13:41]
Photo at 13:41

[image: Photo at 14:43]
Photo at 14:43

The vessel was moving slowly in southerly direction.  It looks like it's either a cruise ship, or a very large (RO-RO) ferry with all cars in the hold; but considering time and location it would have to be on the Belfast–Liverpool route and their ferries on that route (MS Stena Lagan and MS Stena Mersey) are much smaller, and it lacks the characteristic S for Stena.  It's a bit small for a cruise ship.  If it was in Norway I'd say it's one of Hurtigrutens ships, but this is the Irish Sea…

Unfortunately, the lens I was using was not strong enough te resolve the lettering on the vessel.

My camera was located at [Corrins Hill just south of Peel, Isle of Man](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/54.2101/-4.7107).  I was looking north-north-west, back along the coast.  So I would expect the ship to have been located somewhere northwest, or perhaps straight north of Peel.

What vessel did I spot?  How would I determine it?

[MarineTraffic](https://www.marinetraffic.com) offers current vessel position information.  [Vesselfinder](https://www.vesselfinder.com/historical-ais-data) offer historical data, but at a price.

Comment: This isn't really about travel, and if you really badly need the information then you may have to pay at the website you linked to.

Comment: @user16259 It's something I observed during travelling, ship/train/plane-spotting is a traveller's activity, and the pictured ship can be travelled on.  So, I disagree.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have any GPS data from your phone (eg Google location history) or the camera, to narrow the search?

Comment: @user16259 Location yes, direction (compass) no.  Information added.

Comment: NB: I've also asked the question [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vessels/comments/8aqsm8/saw_this_vessel_approx_10_km_nnw_of_peel_isle_of/?ref=share&ref_source=link).

Answer (score 1):

From a [Reddit comment by PodporuchikKJ](https://www.reddit.com/r/vessels/comments/8aqsm8/saw_this_vessel_approx_10_km_nnw_of_peel_isle_of/dx0tgz5/):

> I think it was the Azamara Pursuit. Not clear why she was heading south ( ahead of schedule and killing time?). She docked at a shipyard in Belfast on the 4th for a refit. http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-43641616

Indeed, the look fits with the [Azamara Pursuit info from the cruise company](https://www.azamaraclubcruises.co.uk/our-ships/azamara-pursuit).  It was, in fact, en-route to Belfast, which confuses me because it very much appeared to be heading south.